# Formatear campos con Laravel-Excel

Tags: php, javascript, html, laravel, excel

El siguiente código permite exportar un archivo .CSV haciendo uso de la libreria **maatwebsite/laravel-excel** desde **Laravel 5.2**.

```
Excel::create('Filtro Productos Concentrado', function($excel) use($ini, $fin, $gr)
    {
        $granjas = Granja::all();
        $concentrados = Concentrado::all();
        $productos = PedidoConcentrado::all();
        $pedidos = ConsecutivoConcentrado::all();
        $prods = Pedidoconcentrado::whereBetween('fecha_entrega', [$ini,$fin])->get();
        foreach ($prods as $pr)  
        {
            foreach ($granjas as $g) 
            {
                if ($pr->granja_id == $g->id)
                {
                    foreach ($concentrados as $concentrado) 
                    {
                        if ($pr->concentrado_id == $concentrado->id) 
                        {
                            if ($gr == $g->id)
                            {
                                $productos_db[$pr->id]["granja"] = $g->descripcion_granja;
                                $productos_db[$pr->id]["ref"] = $concentrado->ref_concentrado;
                                $productos_db[$pr->id]["producto"] = $concentrado->nombre_concentrado;
                                $productos_db[$pr->id]["fecha_creacion"] = $pr->fecha_creacion;
                                $productos_db[$pr->id]["fecha_entrega"] = $pr->fecha_entrega;
                                $productos_db[$pr->id]["bultos"] = $pr->no_bultos;
                                $productos_db[$pr->id]["kilos"] = $pr->no_kilos;
                                $productos_db[$pr->id]["tipo_documento"] = $pr->tipo_documento;
                                $productos_db[$pr->id]["prefijo"] = $pr->prefijo;
                                $productos_db[$pr->id]["consecutivo"] = $pr->consecutivo_pedido;
                                $productos_db[$pr->id]["bodega"] = 'XXX';
                                $productos_db[$pr->id]["vendedor"] = '0';
                                $productos_db[$pr->id]["centro_costo"] = $g->centro_costo;
                                $productos_db[$pr->id]["forma_pago"] = $g->forma_pago;
                                $productos_db[$pr->id]["precio_concentrados"] = $g->precio_concentrados;
                            }
                            else if ($gr == '0') 
                            {
                                $productos_db[$pr->id]["granja"] = $g->descripcion_granja;
                                $productos_db[$pr->id]["ref"] = $concentrado->ref_concentrado;
                                $productos_db[$pr->id]["producto"] = $concentrado->nombre_concentrado;
                                $productos_db[$pr->id]["fecha_creacion"] = $pr->fecha_creacion;
                                $productos_db[$pr->id]["fecha_entrega"] = $pr->fecha_entrega;
                                $productos_db[$pr->id]["bultos"] = $pr->no_bultos;
                                $productos_db[$pr->id]["kilos"] = $pr->no_kilos;
                                $productos_db[$pr->id]["tipo_documento"] = $pr->tipo_documento;
                                $productos_db[$pr->id]["prefijo"] = $pr->prefijo;
                                $productos_db[$pr->id]["consecutivo"] = $pr->consecutivo_pedido;
                                $productos_db[$pr->id]["bodega"] = 'XXX'; 
                                $productos_db[$pr->id]["vendedor"] = '0'; 
                                $productos_db[$pr->id]["centro_costo"] = $g->centro_costo;
                                $productos_db[$pr->id]["forma_pago"] = $g->forma_pago;
                                $productos_db[$pr->id]["precio_concentrados"] = $g->precio_concentrados;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        $productos_db = json_decode(json_encode($productos_db), true);
        $excel->sheet('Productos', function($sheet) use($productos_db)
        {

            foreach ($productos_db as $producto_db) 
            {
                $sheet->row(1, ['Fecha de Pedido', 'Tipo de Documento', 'Prefijo','Consecutivo', 'Granja', 'vendedor','Forma de Pago', 'codigo', 'Descripcion', 'Kilos', 'bodega', 'Centro de Costo', 'precio', 'Fecha de Entrega']);

                $row = [];
                $row[0] = $producto_db['fecha_creacion'];
                $row[1] = $producto_db['tipo_documento'];
                $row[2] = $producto_db['prefijo'];
                $row[3] = $producto_db['consecutivo'];
                $row[4] = $producto_db['granja'];
                $row[5] = $producto_db['vendedor'];
                $row[6] = $producto_db['forma_pago'];
                $row[7] = $producto_db['ref'];
                $row[8] = $producto_db["producto"];
                $row[9] = $producto_db['kilos'];
                $row[10] = $producto_db['bodega'];
                $row[11] = $producto_db['centro_costo'];
                $row[12] = $producto_db['precio_concentrados'];
                $row[13] = $producto_db['fecha_entrega'];

                $sheet->appendRow($row);
            }
        });
    })->export('csv');
```

Quisiera que algunas celdas se les predeterminara el tipo de dato como **Texto**, el problema es que al exportarlo Excel las reconoce con formato **General** y me borra el cero a la izquierda que tienen que traer los datos por defecto(sale **7** en vez de **07** como está en la BD).
gracias por su ayuda...

Comment: Quizás te sirva forzar la variable desde php, por ejemplo `$row[laquesea] = (string) $producto_db['valor']`

Answer (score 0):

Podrías dar formato a las columnas de acuerdo a la documentación:

```
$sheet->setColumnFormat(array(
  'B' => '0',
  'D' => '0.00',
  'E' => '@',
  'F' => 'yyyy-mm-dd',
));
```

[(Link a Documentación)](https://laravel-excel.maatwebsite.nl/docs/3.0/export/column-formatting), [(Pregunta en SO en inglés)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29852124/how-to-pre-format-a-cell-to-date-on-laravel-excel)

- Edición 1: El método export de la [clase Sheet](https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel/blob/3.0/src/Sheet.php) no parece funcionar como supones, pues le envías 'csv' y está implementado esperando otra cosa, creo.

  ```
  public function export($sheetExport)
  {
  $this->open($sheetExport);
  if ($sheetExport instanceof FromView) {
      $this->fromView($sheetExport);
  } else {
      if ($sheetExport instanceof FromQuery) {
          $this->fromQuery($sheetExport, $this->worksheet);
      }
      if ($sheetExport instanceof FromCollection) {
          $this->fromCollection($sheetExport, $this->worksheet);
      }
  }
  $this->close($sheetExport);
  }
  ```
- La [documentación](https://laravel-excel.maatwebsite.nl/docs/3.0/export/store) indica que, para guardar con un writer definido, podría usarse el método `store` de la clase `Excel`:

  ```
  // Store on a different disk with a defined writer type. 
  Excel::store(<datasource>, <nombre_archivo_destino>, <disco_destino>, Excel::CSV);
  ```

  Esto debido a que allí sí están definidas las constantes de los tipos de writers y eventualmente ejecuta un export con el `writerType` correcto.

  ```
  $file = $this->export($export, $filePath, $writerType);
  ```

Comment: ¿antes o después de definir el arreglo?

Comment: Creería que no debería importar porque esa librería debe serializar el xls al final de todas las instrucciones. Por organización del código, podría dejarse antes para ver las configuraciones "generales" y luego los detalles particulares :)

Comment: Ya he probado con xls y funciona perfecto, pero el problema empieza cuando necesito CSV

Comment: ¿Qué quieres decir con "Necesito CSV"? Si exportas los datos a un archivo con extensión csv, un editor de texto (p.ej. **notepad, notepad++**, etc) va a ver los datos tal cual. Si abres ese CSV con excel, te va a preguntar qué formato darle a cada columna porque un CSV no guarda ningún metadato sobre formato de columnas. Por favor aclara en tu pregunta sobre lo que estás indicando

Comment: exacto, en el sistema que estoy desarrollando necesito exportar CSV mas no xls, solo que ese archivo csv tiene que subirse a un ERP(software administrativo) y este requiere que se antepongan los ceros

Comment: En la pregunta dices que los datos ya traen el cero o los ceros a la izquierda. Partiendo de eso, sospecho que el problema esta entonces en cómo se está serializando el archivo. Por favor, completa el código en tu pregunta e incluye lo que corresponde a cuando "guardas el archivo" de salida, así como la configuración del objeto `$sheet` que es cuando instancias los objetos relacionados con la librería.

Comment: listo, ya actualice el código

Comment: Amplié la respuesta, espero que sirva